# What is a tool that encrypts data called?

Tags: terminology, programming

If I have a software that encrypts data, how do I refer to it?  'Encryptor'?

Comment: Yes. ***Encrypter***; also, ***encryptor*** 'A thing, such as an algorithm, a program, or a device, that encrypts.' http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/encrypter#English

Comment: *Enigmator? Confabulator?  Obfuscator? Cryptonomicon?* (Whoops. That one is already taken!)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It could be referred to as an **encoder** or as **encryption software/application**.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Encryption_software

Comment: I've accepted you answer cuz it's closer to the one suggested by 'Kris', which is 'Encrypter'. Also 'encoder' looks pretty good.

Comment: @Dor Note, though, that *encoding* and *encryption* are two different things.

Answer (score 1):

Enigma was a [**cipher machine**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Enigma_machine).
Since yours is made of software, it's be a virtual cipher machine.
**Cipher engine** and **Ciphering engine** are also used, and may be more appropriate for a software construct.

Comment: Enigma was indeed a "cipher machine". However, today nobody uses the word "cipher" for serious cryptographic applications. You will give the impression that you know nothing about cryptography, and that your encryption software can be easily broken. Here is [evidence from Google Ngrams](http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=ciphered%2C+encrypted&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=)